# Extract values from list within a spark dataframe without convert to pandas

Tags: pandas, loops, pyspark

I have a spark data frame that looks like the one from below: Each row contains one list, from which I want to extract an element.
I am pretty green at spark, so I convert it into a pandas DataFrame, and then with map functions, I extract the desired elements. The problem is, that the data is huge and therefore this approach is not scalable. What is taking me time is the `toPandas()` command.
Is there an option to access the values within the list from each row?

Thanks!

```
+--------------------+
|            sentence|
+--------------------+
|[{document, 0, 23...|
|[{document, 0, 68...|
|[{document, 0, 65...|
|[{document, 0, 23...|
|[{document, 0, 23...|
|[{document, 0, 23...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: You can use `getItem` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html) to get element from list based on index. If you are looking for more specialized case, share the logic you apply after converting to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can for example crate a new column like this by picking an element from the list on another column by index.

````
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
df = DataFrame()
df = df.withColumn("selected_item", F.col("sentence").getItem(0))```
````